# виртуальный хост в open server

Tags: openserver, virtual-hosts

добавил виртуальный хост в open server ,но выдает Access forbidden.

файл apache vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName      landing.loc
    DocumentRoot    "%sprogdir%/OSPanel/domains/landing.loc/public"
</VirtualHost>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а сама папка с сайтом находится? добавляй сразу папку с проектом в `domains` и не придется создавать никакие настройки. они будут созданы автоматом

Comment: А вы положили в документ рут индексный файл?

Comment: дело в том ,что структура laravel,поэтому через хост указал папку в которой index

Comment: а что не так с laravel? я не в курсе его структуры, но уверен выруливается через htaccess в корне, а еще можно сделать по-другому: если зайти в настройки во вкладку `Домены`, то можно добавить сопоставление. например указать имя домена (landing.loc) и папку проекта (domains/landing.loc/public).... в общем посмотри как раз вот эту вкладку и вкладку `Алиасы`. C openserver это должно быстро вырулиться так

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте в конфиг виртуалхоста

```
# apache 2.4
<Directory "ваш путь/">
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

или

```
# apache 2.2
<Directory "ваш путь/">
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```